# Using \adjustwidth from changepage to make a narrower ToC introduces an extra blank page, how to remove it?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, indentation

I am required to typeset a ToC that is narrower than the `\textwdith` or `\linewidth`. I use the `\adjustwidth` from the `changepage` package for this and it almost works except that it introduces a blank page before the actual ToC page.

I simplified this into a minimal example so you can see what is happening here (please copy & paste these two code blocks into two named files and compile the `narrowtoc.tex`):

### `narrow-toc.cls`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{narrow-toc}

\DeclareOption*{
 \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{report}

\RequirePackage{changepage}

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\let\oldtableofcontents = \tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{
%\clearpage % even after comment out this, there is still a blank page before the toc
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{1cm}
        \oldtableofcontents
    \end{adjustwidth}
}
```

### `narrowtoc.tex`

```
\documentclass{narrow-toc}

\title{A normal title}
\author{My name}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{My first chapter}
Texts

\end{document}
```

The produced pdf file has 4 pages: its "Table of Contents" is in page 3, while page 2 is blank and page 1 is the title page.

How can I remove this blank page 2? Here the report document class is used, so this is not a problem solved by "oneside" option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The environment `adjustwidth` starts a list and then `\oldtableofcontents` issues a `\clearpage` (from `\chapter*`); add `\let\clearpage\relax` to the definition.

```
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{1cm}
     \let\clearpage\relax
     \oldtableofcontents
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \clearpage
}
```

Comment: I did not know the default \tableofcontents issues a \clearpage.. This works. Thanks a lot, egreg!